# Al actualizar muestra el Home siempre

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, nextjs

Estoy trabajando con NextJS, utilicé el yarn export para obtener el sitio estático... funciona todo perfecto pero cuando entraba a una ruta (por medio de un boton o enlace desde la misma web) y le daba F5 por ejemplo, me daba 404 o si ingreso directo a la url.. por lo cual modifique el htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Ahora bien con este puedo entrar con url directa, o desde los enlaces internos, pero si le doy F5... por ejemplo estando en /contacto o en cualquier otra... me sigue mostrando url dominio.com/contacto pero el contenido se muestra el del home!

Alguna idea como solucionarlo?